# Sending email using Telnet

Tags: email, smtp, telnet

I saw many thread about sending email using Telnet, but I couldn't do that.

I'm trying to connect to yahoo smtp server by :

```
telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.com 25
```

The response from server is :

```
Trying 98.138.105.21...
Connected to smtp.mail.yahoo.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
```

My request is :

```
ehlo smtp.mail.yahoo.com
```

The response from server is :

```
250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41697280
250-8 BITMIME
250 STARTTLS
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I don't get `OK` from server to continuing sending mail...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ehlo` request is wrong.

`ehlo` or `helo` should be followed by **client** name and not server.

So you should enter `ehlo your.host.na.me` or `ehlo your.ip.add.ress`.

Can't say if it's related to yahoo server closing connection, but many SMTP servers don't 
allow clients to impersonate them ;)

I just tried:

```
220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready

ehlo 192.168.1.1

250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41697280
250-8 BITMIME
250 STARTTLS

mail from: <>
530 5.7.1 Authentication required

rset
250 2.0.0 OK

quit
```

Comment: Should I type in sender email password after `Authentication required` ?

Comment: What is `rset` ?

Comment: @HamedKamrava `rset` simply *resets* the session so you can start another (i.e. to send another mail). Authentication via telnet can be a bit tricky, as it seems yahoo doesn't support plain authentication. Take a look here: http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/mail/test-smtp-auth-telnet